# TFS pending changes not checked

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

Couldn't find this on google surprisingly:

Looking at my pending changes tab there are files awaiting check-in, but they're not automatically ticked/checked like they have been. I find this feature useful so I don't have to manually tick all the changes.

Another thing I've noticed is that it discerns between batches of changes, i.e. some pending changes are checked and some are not. Upon checking-in the already selected changes, the next batch's changes are automatically checked. How does Visual Studio do this cleverness?

Comment: have you got TFS Power Tools or any other extensions installed on on Visual Studio? From tags, I am assuming it is TFS 2010 & visual studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "batches of changes" but from my experience, if I am working on multiple Solutions, I will see all files that are pending checkin across all Solutions, but only the ones related to the currently open Solution will be checked when I select View Pending Changes.

It took me a bit to get used to, but I quite like it because I can check-in all selected files without worrying about checking in files that are not related to what I'm currently working on.

Comment: I see what you mean and I've noticed that too, but what I've observed is that it is selective of the pending changes within the same solution, as if it's intelligently checking what's *ready* to be checked-in!